# RTSP Validation checking

Tags: streaming, vlc, rtsp, ip-camera

Is there any method to check whether RTSP url contains stream availability using command line mode. I want to check the stream availability before calling the url in my program

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the headers for rtsp : http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtsp-parameters/rtsp-parameters.xhtml, it should be useful, but you will always need to call the url. Other option is if you control the streaming server, host a http server that can return status of the stream.

Comment: Thanks, let me check it